# How to redirect in PHP?

Tags: php, redirect

Searched the web for the past hour and none of the solutions worked for me.

Both my signUp or login functions don't redirect.

I'm not doing any echo's before I set my header.

My current code:

```
<?php
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/Model/User/UserDto.php');
    require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/Model/FacadeFactory.php');

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    $action();

    function signUp() {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $userDto = new UserDto($email, $password);
        FacadeFactory::getDomainFacade()->signUp($userDto);
        FacadeFactory::getDomainFacade()->login($userDto);


        $location = sprintf("Location: %s%s",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "/View/Dashboard");
        header($location);
        exit();
    }

    function login() {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $userDto = new UserDto($email, $password);
        FacadeFactory::getDomainFacade()->login($userDto);

        $location = sprintf("Location: %s%s",$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"], "/View/Dashboard");
        ob_start();
        header($location);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: And when setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, you don't get a warning regarding` Headers already sent`?

Comment: remove exit() also, print what is in $location.

Comment: The exit is fine actually. Will never be reached, but it wont hurt. And it's actually a best practice to exit/return after a redirect. This makes sure an error in `header()` wont allow your code to continue even if it shouldn't.

Comment: @Joey: your can ommit your http_host in your redirects. '/View/Dashboard' will work just fine.

Comment: while testing in local system sometimes $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] is not set

Comment: @DamienOvereem Thank you!! I removed the http_host and it worked!

Comment: Added it as an answer so you can 'close' the question. And you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` is unneccesary in your `header('Location: ')`. You can just leave it out and use `header("Location: /View/Dashboard");`.